# How to filter table (visible option) when is clicked dropdown select tag

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have problem with filtering my table. Table is formed with data from database. I have 5 columns where values are 1 or 0 (int) - depends what user clicked in sing-in form.
Beside, i have select tag where i have those 5 options.
I need a solution. If i click one of options, whole rows disapear where that same name column is 0.

```
<select name="filter">
    <option value="none">No filter</option>
    <option value="value1" onclick="function1()">value1</option>
    <option value="value2" onclick="function2()">value2</option>
    <option value="value3" onclick="function3()">value3</option>
    <option value="value4" onclick="function4()">value4</option>
    <option value="value5" onclick="function5()">value5</option>
</select>
```

This down is piece of whole table where i have 1 or 0 values. And output from table is working properly.

```
<td <input type="hidden" name="value1" value="<?=$row['value1']?>"><?=$row['value1']?></td>
<td <input type="hidden" name="value2" value="<?=$row['value2']?>"><?=$row['value2']?></td>
<td <input type="hidden" name="value3" value="<?=$row['value3']?>"><?=$row['value3']?></td>
<td <input type="hidden" name="value4" value="<?=$row['value4']?>"><?=$row['value4']?></td>
<td <input type="hidden" name="value5" value="<?=$row['value5']?>"><?=$row['value5']?></td>



EDIT (source):

<td> <input type="hidden" name="value1" value="1">1</td>
<td> <input type="hidden" name="value2" value="0">0</td>
<td> <input type="hidden" name="value3" value="1">1</td>
<td> <input type="hidden" name="value4" value="1">1</td>
<td> <input type="hidden" name="value5" value="0">0</td>
```

EDIT (pictures):

First pic without any filter (first select option "without filtering"):
[1st pic link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiU5Y.png)

Second picture (select second value filtering -> third value in select
options because first one is "without filtering"):
[2nd pic link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VxSr.png)
As we can see it works but i need to remove complete row instead only cell.

Picture for last value filter (same problem, but it works):
[3rd pic link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KIE7.png)

Comment: Please add the rendered HTML showing the actual content of the table (ie: view source and copy from that )

Comment: Hi there, this is acctualy my code, but i can copy paste here what i got from source (value1, value2.. are different, but to be more simple i give here just like that)

Comment: The above HTML is badly formed - note `<td <input` ~ the TD tag is unclosed in every instance

Comment: I see it. Just if i put second `>` program just print it together with number in table. It goes `>1` and like this it works.
Maybe i can just close it like `<td>` ?

Comment: sorry - I don't know what you mean. Did the answer below do what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, with big help from  [Professor Abronsius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3603681/professor-abronsius) i have final solution.

And it works perfect!

```
    <script>
    // Find all the hidden inputs within the table rows/cells
    const col=document.querySelectorAll('td input[type="hidden"]');

    // assign an event listener to the select menu that processes "change" events
    document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change',function(e){

        // ensure that all table-rows are visible
        col.forEach(n=>n.parentNode.style.display='table-cell');
        
        // if the user selects an option from the menu ( other than the 1st one )
        // find the corresponding hidden input (based upon name & value) and hide it
        if( this.options.selectedIndex > 0 ){
            // save all rows in one variable and catching row by row with loop
            let tr=document.querySelectorAll(`input[name="${this.value}"][value="0"]`);
            //dividing by 9 is because i have 9 cells 
            for (var i = 0; i < (col.length/9); i++){
                if( tr[i]!==null ) tr[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.display='none';
            }
        }
        // again, when is clicked "without filter" shows all rows
        if( this.options.selectedIndex == 0 ){
            col.forEach(n=>n.parentNode.parentNode.style.display='table-row');
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly straightforward to accomplish the stated objective with some basic javascript. You do not need 5 separate functions ( none of which you showed for some reason ) but you do need to refine your HTML and ensure the tags are properly closed & nested.

```js
// Find all the hidden inputs within the table rows/cells
const col=document.querySelectorAll('tr td input[type="hidden"]');

// assign an event listener to the select menu that processes "change" events
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change',function(e){

  // ensure that all table-rows are visible
  col.forEach(n=>n.parentNode.style.display='table-cell');

  // if the user selects an option from the menu ( other than the 1st one )
  // find the corresponding hidden input (based upon name & value) and hide it
  if( this.options.selectedIndex > 0 ){
  
    let tr=document.querySelector(`input[name="${this.value}"][value="0"]`);
    if( tr!==null ) tr.parentNode.style.display='none';
  }
});
```

```css
table{border:1px solid grey;background:pink;margin:0.25rem 0}
td{padding:1rem;border:1px dotted grey;background:white}
select{padding:1rem;margin:0.25rem 0}
```

```html
<select name="filter">
  <option value="none">No filter</option>
  <option value="value1">value1</option>
  <option value="value2">value2</option>
  <option value="value3">value3</option>
  <option value="value4">value4</option>
  <option value="value5">value5</option>
</select>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="value1" value="1">1 - #VALUE1#</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="value2" value="0">0 - #VALUE2#</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="value3" value="1">1 - #VALUE3#</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="value4" value="1">1 - #VALUE4#</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="value5" value="0">0 - #VALUE5#</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried with some solutions from web but it didnt work...

Idk if you understood mine problem, seems like this is real good soilution but it did not work for me, it remove first row and nothing else, for every option..

Is there problem if these values are starting from 11th td?

I have all together 21 column. First is checkbox, next 11 of them are irrelevant (name, surname...) next 9 of them ARE important (with values 0 or 1) and last one is delete icon 

I need function for just this 9 one columns...tried to adjust your function but didnt work..

Comment: Sorry for annoyance..

and i have ONE `<tr>` element for ALL `<td>` elements

Comment: `"If i click one of options, **whole rows** disapear where that same name column is 0"` - hence the confusion on my behalf

Comment: Great, we found mistake..
Options in select tag are same like these 9 columns where values are 0 or 1.

If i click one of options (in this case value1, value2,... in `<select name="filter">` tag), we are looking values (0or1) in column with **excatly same name** . If there is 0 value => whole row disapear, but if there is 1, it stays visible

Comment: In that case it should be easier to mark bulk of users and do some functions on them